# Convolutions with shared memory in CUDA

Tags: c, signal-processing, cuda

I am writing a noise blur convolution kernel in CUDA

```
__global__ void noiseReduction(float *im, float *NR, int height, int width)
{
    // Definition
    int i, j, bi, bj;

    // Retrieve global id
    i = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y*blockIdx.y + 2;
    j = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + 2;  

    // Retrieve id within block
    bi = threadIdx.y + 2;
    bj = threadIdx.x + 2;

    /* Shared memory preparation */
    __shared__ float im_shared[2 + int(BLOCKSIZE) + 2][2 + int(BLOCKSIZE) + 2];

    // Load left superior corner
    if (2 <= bi && bi < 4 && 2 <= bj && bj < 4){
        im_shared[bi-2][bj-2] = im[(i-2)*width + j - 2];
    }

    // Load left superior corner
    if (2 <= bi && bi < 4 && 2 <= bj && bj < 4){
        im_shared[bi-2][bj-2] = im[(i-2)*width + j - 2];
    }

    // Load right superior corner
    if (2 <= bi && bi < 4 && BLOCKSIZE <= bj && bj < BLOCKSIZE + 2){
        im_shared[bi-2][bj+2] = im[(i-2)*width + j + 2];
    }

    // Load left inferior corner
    if (BLOCKSIZE <= bi && bi <= BLOCKSIZE + 2 && 2 <= bj && bj < 4){
        im_shared[bi+2][bj-2] = im[(i+2)*width + j - 2];
    }

    // Load right inferior corner
    if (BLOCKSIZE <= bi && bi <= BLOCKSIZE + 2 && BLOCKSIZE <= bj && bj < BLOCKSIZE + 2){
        im_shared[bi+2][bj+2] = im[(i+2)*width + j + 2];
    }

    // Load superior edge
    if (2 <= bi && bi < 4){
        im_shared[bi-2][bj] = im[(i-2)*width + j];
    }

    // Load inferior edge
    if (BLOCKSIZE <= bi && bi <= BLOCKSIZE + 2){
        im_shared[bi+2][bj] = im[(i+2)*width + j];
    }

    // Load left edge
    if (2 <= bj && bj < 4){
        im_shared[bi][bj-2] = im[i*width + j - 2];
    }

    // Load right edge
    if (BLOCKSIZE <= bj && bj < BLOCKSIZE + 2){
        im_shared[bi][bj+2] = im[i*width + j + 2];
    }

    // Load center data
    im_shared[bi][bj] = im[i*width + j];

    __syncthreads();

    // Noise reduction
    if (i < height-2 && j < width - 2) 
    {
        NR[i*width+j] =
             (2.0*im_shared[bi-2][bj-2] +  4.0*im_shared[bi-2][bj-1] +  5.0*im_shared[bi-2][bj] +  4.0*im_shared[bi-2][bj+1] + 2.0*im_shared[bi-2][bj+2]
            + 4.0*im_shared[bi-1][bj-2] +  9.0*im_shared[bi-1][bj-1] + 12.0*im_shared[bi-1][bj] +  9.0*im_shared[bi-1][bj+1] + 4.0*im_shared[bi-1][bj+2]
            + 5.0*im_shared[bi  ][bj-2] + 12.0*im_shared[bi  ][bj-1] + 15.0*im_shared[bi  ][bj] + 12.0*im_shared[bi  ][bj+1] + 5.0*im_shared[bi  ][bj+2]
            + 4.0*im_shared[bi+1][bj-2] +  9.0*im_shared[bi+1][bj-1] + 12.0*im_shared[bi+1][bj] +  9.0*im_shared[bi+1][bj+1] + 4.0*im_shared[bi+1][bj+2]
            + 2.0*im_shared[bi+2][bj-2] +  4.0*im_shared[bi+2][bj-1] +  5.0*im_shared[bi+2][bj] +  4.0*im_shared[bi+2][bj+1] + 2.0*im_shared[bi+2][bj+2])
            /159.0;
    }
}

void blurGPU(float *im, float *image_out,
    int height, int width)
{
    /* Definitions */
    float *im_GPU, *image_out_GPU;

    /* Malloc GPU */
    cudaMalloc((void **) &im_GPU, height*width*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void **) &image_out_GPU, height*width*sizeof(float));


    /* Copy input to GPU */
    cudaMemcpy(im_GPU, im, height*width*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    /* Call kernels */
    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCKSIZE,BLOCKSIZE,1);
    dim3 dimGrid(ceil((width-2) / BLOCKSIZE),ceil((height-2) / BLOCKSIZE),1);

    // Noise reduction
    noiseReduction<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(im_GPU, image_out_GPU, height, width);
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(image_out, image_out_GPU, height*width*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    /* Free GPU */
    cudaFree(im_GPU);
    cudaFree(image_out_GPU);

}
```

The idea is that each thread loads to shared memory the pixels that correspond to their location, and the threads close to the border of each thread block also take care of loading the neighbouring pixels from other blocks (the "apron" part of the convolution)

It seems to be working, but its hard to tell at glance if there is a subtle mistake.

Plus I wrote a lot of manual code to load the "apron", and I cannot shake the feeling that there should be a more elegant way of writing this.

And of course I could be missing some big things for performance.

Any tips for a CUDA beginner? I am specially interested in testing, improving the code style and improving performance.

Comment: This is C++, not C as you labelled it. The cast `int(BLOCKSIZE)` is invalid C code.